# missing generics for trait `actix_service::Service` --> src/middleware.rs:57:8

Tags: rust, traits, actix-web, casbin

How do I implement traits? On running cargo build I get this error.
Also I commented out `type Request = ServiceRequest;`. How would this affect the code? I updated actix-service to 2.0.0-beta.2 in Cargo.toml, then the build failed.

```
error[E0107]: missing generics for trait `actix_service::Service`
  --> src/middleware.rs:57:8
   |
57 |     S: Service<Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
   |        ^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
   |
note: trait defined here, with 1 type parameter: `Req`
  --> /home/samarpan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/actix-service-2.0.0-beta.5/src/lib.rs:85:11
   |
85 | pub trait Service<Req> {
   |           ^^^^^^^ ---
help: use angle brackets to add missing type argument
   |
57 |     S: Service<Req><Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
   |               ^^^^^
```

This is my middleware.rs -

```
#![allow(clippy::type_complexity)]

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

use futures::future::{ok, Ready};
use futures::Future;

use actix_service::{Service, Transform};
use actix_web::{
    dev::ServiceRequest, dev::ServiceResponse, Error, HttpMessage, HttpResponse, Result,
};

use casbin::prelude::{TryIntoAdapter, TryIntoModel};
use casbin::{CachedEnforcer, CoreApi, Result as CasbinResult};

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-tokio")]
use tokio::sync::RwLock;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-async-std")]
use async_std::sync::RwLock;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct CasbinVals {
    pub subject: String,
    pub domain: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct CasbinService {
    enforcer: Arc<RwLock<CachedEnforcer>>,
}

impl CasbinService {
    pub async fn new<M: TryIntoModel, A: TryIntoAdapter>(m: M, a: A) -> CasbinResult<Self> {
        let enforcer: CachedEnforcer = CachedEnforcer::new(m, a).await?;
        Ok(CasbinService {
            enforcer: Arc::new(RwLock::new(enforcer)),
        })
    }

    pub fn get_enforcer(&mut self) -> Arc<RwLock<CachedEnforcer>> {
        self.enforcer.clone()
    }

    pub fn set_enforcer(e: Arc<RwLock<CachedEnforcer>>) -> CasbinService {
        CasbinService { enforcer: e }
    }
}

impl<S, B> Transform<S, B> for CasbinService
where
    S: Service<Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    //type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = CasbinMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(CasbinMiddleware {
            enforcer: self.enforcer.clone(),
            service: Rc::new(RefCell::new(service)),
        })
    }
}
impl Deref for CasbinService {
    type Target = Arc<RwLock<CachedEnforcer>>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.enforcer
    }
}

impl DerefMut for CasbinService {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.enforcer
    }
}

pub struct CasbinMiddleware<S> {
    service: Rc<RefCell<S>>,
    enforcer: Arc<RwLock<CachedEnforcer>>,
}

impl<S, B> Service<B> for CasbinMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    //type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>>>;

    fn poll_ready(&self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.service.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&mut self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let cloned_enforcer = self.enforcer.clone();
        let mut srv = self.service.clone();

        Box::pin(async move {
            let path = req.path().to_string();
            let action = req.method().as_str().to_string();
            let option_vals = req.extensions().get::<CasbinVals>().map(|x| x.to_owned());
            let vals = match option_vals {
                Some(value) => value,
                None => {
                    return Ok(req.into_response(HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish().into_body()))
                }
            };
            let subject = vals.subject.clone();

            if !vals.subject.is_empty() {
                if let Some(domain) = vals.domain {
                    let mut lock = cloned_enforcer.write().await;
                    match lock.enforce_mut(vec![subject, domain, path, action]) {
                        Ok(true) => {
                            drop(lock);
                            srv.call(req).await
                        }
                        Ok(false) => {
                            drop(lock);
                            Ok(req.into_response(HttpResponse::Forbidden().finish().into_body()))
                        }
                        Err(_) => {
                            drop(lock);
                            Ok(req.into_response(HttpResponse::BadGateway().finish().into_body()))
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    let mut lock = cloned_enforcer.write().await;
                    match lock.enforce_mut(vec![subject, path, action]) {
                        Ok(true) => {
                            drop(lock);
                            srv.call(req).await
                        }
                        Ok(false) => {
                            drop(lock);
                            Ok(req.into_response(HttpResponse::Forbidden().finish().into_body()))
                        }
                        Err(_) => {
                            drop(lock);
                            Ok(req.into_response(HttpResponse::BadGateway().finish().into_body()))
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Ok(req.into_response(HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish().into_body()))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

original repo link - https://github.com/casbin-rs/actix-casbin-auth

my changes - https://github.com/smrpn/actix-casbin-auth/tree/feature/bumpactixweb

Answer (score 0):

The `Service` trait has a generic type parameter that is required, but you're not setting it. You'we done it where you're implementing `Service` (by changing it from `Service` to `Service<B>`) and `Transform` (by changing it from `Transform<S>` to `Transform<S, T>`), however you didn't change it where you're using `Service` as a trait bound (i.e. `S: Service<...>`). Following the other changes that should also change from `S: Service<Request = ...>` to `S: Service<B, Request = ...>`.

Note that this will fix the error you mentioned, but not the others. I'm not familiar with `actix-service`, but from what I saw to keep the code consistent with how it was before you should change `Transform<S>` to `Transform<S, ServiceRequest>`, `Service` to `Service<ServiceRequest>` and `S: Service<Response=...>` to `S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response=...>`